# Woocommerce Переместить Доставку в отдельный блок

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

На мобильной версии "Доставка" находится под блоком с данными и выбором адреса. Получается, если пользователь хочет выбрать другой метод доставки, ему нужно пройти первый блок, где указываются данные, потом дойти до низа и увидеть, что оказывается, можно выбрать другой способ доставки. Он нажимает и форма сверху обновляется, данные уже нужны другие, ему нужно скроллить вверх. Это крайне неудобно.

Можно ли как-то вынести в самый верх блок с выбором метода?

Для понимания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Картинки должны быть прямо в теле вопроса.

Comment: @KAGGDesign вывел

Comment: У вас просто поля для выбора отделений и всего прочего не там находятся :) У вуки в отдельном блоке находятся вся информация о доставке

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось переопределить файлы шаблона.

Из файла `review-order.php` я забрал этот код:

```
<?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

    <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

И вставил его в `form-billing.php` после `h3`